# Autologin user after registration Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, passwords, autologin

I am trying to autologin a user after registration.

I am trying this in `functions.php` file:

```
    add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_user' );
    function auto_login_user($user_id) {
      $user = new WP_User($user_id);
      $user_login_var = $user->user_login;
      $user_email_var = stripslashes($user->user_email);
      $user_pass_var    = $user->user_pass;
      $creds = array();
      $creds['user_login'] = $user_login_var;
      $creds['user_password'] = $user_pass_var;
      $creds['remember'] = true;
      $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
      if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
        
}
```

**I am getting  ERROR**:

> The password you entered for the username "TheNewUserCreated" is incorrect. Lost your password?

How Can I take the password from the User object?

Also because this is a custom registration process in template registration.php I tried to take it with $_POST and run the function in that file but I didnt have any success that way too...

**EDIT:**
Ok I am getting the encrypted password, so what is the solution here, how can I autologin the user? Maybe I can do this in registration.php page?

Answer (score 8):

Add below function to `functions.php` file

```
 function auto_login_new_user( $user_id ) {
        wp_set_current_user($user_id);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
            // You can change home_url() to the specific URL,such as 
        //wp_redirect( 'http://www.wpcoke.com' );
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
 add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_new_user' );
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `wp_insert_user();` to register your users then to auto-login them it's simple.
This function returns the user ID if success, so use it to login that user.

```
$id = wp_insert_user($data);
//so if the return is not an wp error object then continue with login
if(!is_wp_error($id)){
    wp_set_current_user($id); // set the current wp user
    wp_set_auth_cookie($id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
}
```

but to follow what you have already it can be like this:

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'auto_login_user' );
function auto_login_user($user_id) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id); // set the current wp user
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id); // start the cookie for the current registered user
}
//this code is a bit tricky, if you are admin and you want to create a user then your admin session will be replaced with the new user you created :)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function auto_login() {
            $getuserdata=get_user_by('login',$_GET['login']);
            $tuserid=$getuserdata->ID;
            $user_id = $tuserid;
            $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
            if( $user ) {
                wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
                wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
                do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );

            }
        }
        add_action('init', 'auto_login');
```

i had have the same problem as your and found this best solution. try this in your functions.php file. and one thing more use submit your reset form in a function in functions.php file